# Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-android

```
 A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Failed to read key locii from store "E:\Flutter-App\android\app\locii.jks": No key with alias 'locii' found in keysto
re E:\Flutter-App\android\app\locii.jks
```

BUILD FAILED in 1m 46s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            107.7s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: locii.jks file not found in the path .

Answer (score 0):

Your jks file not found in the path just check where you the jks file provide the correct path